# Surface Pro to Apple thunderbolt display 27

Tags: displayport, thunderbolt-display

Want to display the Surface Pro in a second monitor that is a Apple Thunderbolt Display 27.

Surface has Mini Display port 
Apple has Thunderbolt cable

both are physically the same but the tech is different.

What can i do to send image to the Apple Display ?

tks for the help !

Answer (score 3):

Nope, not possible, Apple Thunderbolt Display requires a Thunderbolt port which the Surface Pro and Pre-2011 MacBooks don't have (even though mini-DisplayPort have exactly the same connector).